# C++\Qt Получение доступа к компонентам

Tags: c++, qt

В программе есть компоненты, которые отвечают за определенный функционал. Компонент реализован при помощи MVC, (классы Model, Controller, View).
Есть класс главного окна MainWindow. Каждый класс Controller подключается в него. Нужно чтобы каждый Controller имел доступ к другому, даже к модели.

Решением может быть создание класса приложения Application, в которое подключаются все классы Controller, и MainWindow. Сделать пространство имен, в котором сделать 
функцию которая будет возвращать указатель на объект Application. Через указать получается доступ к Controller.

В Controller сделать public метод model() который вернет модель.

Comment: "Нужно чтобы каждый Controller имел доступ к другому, даже к модели".
Есть подозрение, что имеется проблема с архитектурой

Comment: Нужен доступ потому что в контроллере создается запись данных, в которой есть внешний ключ из модели другого контроллера. И в диалоге пользователь выбирает запись из той модели.

Comment: Данные второго контроллера отображены в главном окне. В первом контроллере вызывается диалог для выбора записей. То есть, я не хочу создавать еще одну модель, а сослаться на ту, которая уже есть в памяти, но в другом контроллере.

Comment: Если компонент это то, что может функционировать без другого, то значит я неправильно разделил на компоненты? Но если в модели реляционная связь.